# Editing existing custom document set content types - How?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set

I'm looking all over the internet trying to find documentation on how to edit already existing document set content types. why on earth does Microsoft make it so hard to find documentation on common things? Drives me nuts. Does anyone know?

Comment: It is not recommended to edit the default document set content type in any manner. Instead you should make your own custom content type which is based in the built-in document set content type, and customize it was you desire.

Comment: that's what I am trying to do. update of what appears to be a custom document set content type.

Comment: also note that the parent of the custom document set is default document set that's built in.

Comment: Then you should be able to locate your custom document set's content type through the site settings > content type settings. Note that the content type may inherit from a parent level of the site you are currently at. This means that you also need to have the required permissions at the site level the content type inherits from.

Comment: ok I actually found that. it appears to be in a document set content type group. How can the content type group be edited?

Comment: Found it. It was on a content type publishing HUB. After that things were easy to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I could not find or edit that content types settings for the "new" document button for the document set is because those content types were located on a Content Type Publishing HUB. It was there that all edits were easily administered as opposed editing directly on the site's content type's settings which were not available on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Moe's given you some good advice.  Here are some links I've found useful on this subject too.

[This one](https://sharepointmaven.com/implement-document-management-system-sharepoint/) is a good starting point on content types.  See [section 3](https://sharepointmaven.com/configure-sharepoint-document-library/) of the same SP Maven blog is also useful.

This one is from [John White](https://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2011/02/using-document-templates-with-lists-and-content-types-in-sharepoint/) is more detailed and gives some extra ideas including attaching templates to document content types, which is interesting, though not what you've explicitly asked for.

Comment: OK I found the issue. The settings for the content type was located on a "Content type publishing HUB".  There is very documentation on this.